# Unity for 3D Simulation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My team currently needs to create a visual simulator for some track hardware that we have.

We tried using X3DOM, but the amount of data we were sending it proved to be more than it could take.  (I ended up refreshing every 3 seconds.)

We are currently looking for a replacement that can handle a fairly significant input stream.

Unity 3D came up as a possibility.  However, I know that it is usually used for games.

I will not need any kind of Physics Engine or other similar features.

I will feed all the coordinates into it and then want it to show these objects moving on a track too the coordinates I specify.

Does unity fit for that?

Comment: Yes, Unity is fit for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can input those coordinates in Unity and then track those objects. My team is currently using Unity3D for something similar and we input complex data structures with pose matrices, etc..

You can import your 3D objects into Unity as well. I import .obj into Unity.